# Upgrade to 14.10 fails with UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, unicode

Here is the problem, when running sudo do-release-upgrade and trying to upgrade from 14.04 I receive the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 
826: invalid start byte
```

I have checked previous suggestions and:

- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty (no hidden files)
- there are no non-utf characters in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (`file sources.list`returns `ASCII text`)
- I have removed all temporary folders from `/tmp`
- I have installed all locales and set the variables appropriately

Running `locale` prints:

```
$ locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The process succeeds in finding the update and reading cache, etc., but breaks during the phase in which candidates are identified, in particular, always after

```
No candidate ver:  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol
```

Here is the contents of the /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log

```
2014-10-29 11:08:19,869 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg']'
2014-10-29 11:08:19,869 INFO uname information: 'Linux DCS-MM-L 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64'
2014-10-29 11:08:19,869 INFO apt version: '1.0.1ubuntu2'
2014-10-29 11:08:19,869 INFO python version: '3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2]'
2014-10-29 11:08:19,870 INFO release-upgrader version '14.10.9' started
2014-10-29 11:08:19,883 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2014-10-29 11:08:19,889 INFO screen could not be run
2014-10-29 11:08:19,979 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2014-10-29 11:08:20,031 DEBUG aufsOptionsAndEnvironmentSetup()
2014-10-29 11:08:20,033 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-rw-jgs0kv6u' as aufs_rw_dir
2014-10-29 11:08:20,033 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-chroot-tz80q3ga' as aufs chroot dir
2014-10-29 11:08:20,034 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2014-10-29 11:08:20,047 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2014-10-29 11:08:20,721 DEBUG lsb-release: 'trusty'
2014-10-29 11:08:20,724 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2014-10-29 11:08:20,725 DEBUG openCache()
2014-10-29 11:08:20,726 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2014-10-29 11:08:20,726 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2014-10-29 11:08:20,726 DEBUG plugins for condition 'utopicPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2014-10-29 11:08:20,726 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_trustyPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2014-10-29 11:08:20,727 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2014-10-29 11:08:20,727 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2014-10-29 11:08:20,946 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 15307
2014-10-29 11:08:20,946 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2014-10-29 11:08:20,946 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2014-10-29 11:08:20,946 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2014-10-29 11:08:33,253 DEBUG openCache()
2014-10-29 11:08:34,573 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 15307
2014-10-29 11:08:34,573 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2014-10-29 11:08:34,573 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2014-10-29 11:08:34,573 DEBUG plugins for condition 'utopicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2014-10-29 11:08:34,573 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_trustyPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2014-10-29 11:08:35,611 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'account-plugin-generic-oauth', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,612 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'akonadi-backend-mysql', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,613 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'apache2.2-common', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,614 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'appmenu-gtk', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,614 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'appmenu-gtk3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,621 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'bsh-gcj', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,625 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'conky-all', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,625 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'conky-std', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,637 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'evolution-data-server-goa', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,647 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'foomatic-filters', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,660 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'gnome-control-center-datetime', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,663 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'gnuplot-nox', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,677 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'jockey-common', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,677 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'jockey-kde', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,677 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'kde-runtime', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,677 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'kde-runtime-data', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,678 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'kdepim-runtime', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,699 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-calendar4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,699 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-contact4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,699 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-kabc4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-kcal4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-kde4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-kmime4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-notes4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadi-socialutils4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libakonadiprotocolinternals1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,700 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libamd2.2.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,707 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libaudclient2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,709 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libavcodec53', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,709 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libavfilter2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,709 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libavutil51', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,710 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libbaloocore4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,710 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libbaloofiles4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,710 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libbalooxapian4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,710 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libbamf3-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,711 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libbibutils2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,712 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-date-time1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,712 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-date-time1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,712 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-filesystem1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,713 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-filesystem1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,713 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-iostreams1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,713 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-iostreams1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,713 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-program-options1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,713 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-random1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,714 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-random1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,714 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-regex1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,714 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-regex1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,714 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-system1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,714 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-system1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,715 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-thread1.49.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,715 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libboost-thread1.53.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,715 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libbrlapi0.5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,718 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcamel-1.2-40', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,718 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcamel-1.2-43', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,724 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcmis-0.3-3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,724 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcogl-pango12', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,724 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcogl12', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,724 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcolamd2.7.1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,725 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcolumbus0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,726 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libcommons-validator-java', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,731 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdb5.1-java-jni', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,731 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdb5.1:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,737 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdmtx0a', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,737 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdns95', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,737 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdns99', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,738 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdotconf1.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,739 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdvbpsi7', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,739 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libdynamite0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,740 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libebackend-1.2-5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,740 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libebackend-1.2-6', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,740 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libebml3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,740 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libecal-1.2-15', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,741 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libechonest2.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,741 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libedata-book-1.2-15', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,741 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libedata-book-1.2-17', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,741 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libedata-cal-1.2-18', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,741 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libedata-cal-1.2-20', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,742 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libedataserver-1.2-17', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,744 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libenet1a', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,744 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libepub0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,745 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libev4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,755 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgc1c3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,756 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgcj12', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,756 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgcj13', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,757 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgd2-xpm', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,764 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libglee0d1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,766 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libglew1.8', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,766 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libglewmx1.8', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,768 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgnome-desktop-3-4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,770 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgoa-1.0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,771 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgphoto2-2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,772 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgphoto2-port0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,773 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgranite1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,778 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgtksourceview-3.0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,779 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libguichan-0.8.1-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,779 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libguichan-opengl-0.8.1-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,779 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libguichan-sdl-0.8.1-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,780 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgweather-3-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,780 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libgweather-3-3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,780 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libhal1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,781 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libharfbuzz0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,781 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libharfbuzz0:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,781 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libharfbuzz0a', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,781 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libharfbuzz0a:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,784 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libibus-1.0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,784 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libibus-1.0-0:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,785 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libical0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,785 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libicu48', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,785 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libicu48:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,787 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libimobiledevice3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,789 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libisc92', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,794 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkabc4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,794 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkactivities-models1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,794 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkactivities6', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,794 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkadm5clnt-mit8', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,795 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkalarmcal2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,795 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkatepartinterfaces4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,795 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkcal4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,795 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkcalcore4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,795 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkcalutils4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,795 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkdb5-6', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,796 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkfbapi1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,797 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkgapi2-2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,797 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkholidays4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,797 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkimap4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,797 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkldap4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,798 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkmbox4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,798 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkmime4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,798 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkolab0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,799 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkolabxml0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,799 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkolabxml1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,799 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkpimidentities4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,799 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkpimtextedit4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,799 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkpimutils4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,800 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkresources4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,800 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkubuntu0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,801 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libkxmlrpcclient4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,802 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'liblcms1:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,805 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libllvm3.2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,805 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libllvm3.2:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,805 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libllvm3.3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,806 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libllvm3.3:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,812 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmailtransport4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,812 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmatroska5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,814 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmicroblog4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,816 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmjpegutils-2.0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,816 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmlt5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,817 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmng1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,817 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmng1:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,822 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmpc2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,823 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmpeg2encpp-2.0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,823 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libmplex2-2.0-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,826 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libnepomukcleaner4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,826 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libnepomukcore4abi1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,831 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libntrack-qt4-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,831 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libntrack0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,835 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'liborange0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,838 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libpackagekit-glib2-14', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,848 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libpoppler28', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,848 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libpoppler43', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,849 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libppl12', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,849 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libprison0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,850 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libprocps0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,850 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libprotobuf-lite7', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,850 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libprotobuf7', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,850 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libprotoc7', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,852 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libpyside1.1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,854 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libpython3.3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,854 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqapt2', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,854 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqapt2-runtime', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,855 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqmobipocket1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,856 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqpdf10', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,856 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqrencode3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,858 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqt5core5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,861 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libqt5v8-5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,864 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libraw5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,870 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'librhythmbox-core6', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,870 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'librhythmbox-core7', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,875 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libshiboken1.1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,879 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libsnmp15', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,885 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libsync-menu1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,885 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libsyncdaemon-1.0-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,885 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libsynce0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,887 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libtasn1-3', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,887 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libtasn1-3:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,892 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libtotem-plparser17', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,894 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libumfpack5.4.0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,895 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libunity-core-6.0-5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,895 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libunity-core-6.0-8', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,896 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libunshield0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,899 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libv8-3.8.9.20', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,900 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libvlccore5', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,904 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libwebp4', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,904 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libwebp4:i386', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,909 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libxatracker1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,914 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libxcb-sync0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,916 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libxerces-c3.1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,920 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'libxmmsclient6', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,928 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-20-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-22-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-25-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,929 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-26-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,930 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,930 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,930 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,930 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-30-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,930 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,930 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-20-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-21-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-22-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-25-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-26-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-27-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-30-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,931 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-31-generic', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,941 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'moka-icon-theme', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,941 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'moka-icon-theme-blue', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,941 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'moka-icon-theme-dark', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,946 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'nepomuk-core-data', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,951 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'ntrack-module-libnl-0', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,959 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'oxygen-icon-theme', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,966 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'polkit-kde-1', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,969 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'psensor', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,990 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'python-ubuntuone-client', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:35,990 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol', skipping 
2014-10-29 11:08:36,013 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-fu5bcecr/utopic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-fu5bcecr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 239, in main
    if app.run():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-fu5bcecr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1822, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-fu5bcecr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1707, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-fu5bcecr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 893, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.tasks = self.cache.installedTasks

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-fu5bcecr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 778, in installedTasks
    for line in pkg._pcache._records.record.split("\n"):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 826: invalid start byte

2014-10-29 11:08:36,014 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a few days of unsuccessful trials I have identified the offending package. It turns out that the [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php) editor was messing up the system. After I removed the package the upgrade proceeds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

0x92 is one of [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)'s infamous [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_electronic_documents). Are you sure that there wasn't a file edited/created on a Windows machine that made it choke?

This character wouldn't show up as Unicode, as it's not valid on its own.

Comment: No, it is not that. I would rather think that it has something to do with apt-cache, I was trying to dump the information about all packages and search there for offending characters, but to no avail. Also, I've tracked the error to the _lookupPkgRecord(self, pkg) procedure in DistUpgradeCache.py script, but I can't find any place where the notion of "Tasks" is generated (this is when the script fails).